# Run-Time error '1004' Formula error

Tags: excel, algorithm

I have one problem trying to get this formulain in a excel macro:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A13,"<>"),(COUNTIFS('Night Shift'!O:O,"Ongoing",'Night Shift'!K:K,TEXT(A13,""))+COUNTIFS('Night Shift'!O:O,"Ongoing",'Night Shift'!L:L,TEXT(A13,""))+COUNTIFS('Los Angeles Night Shift'!O:O,"Ongoing",'Los Angeles Night Shift'!K:K,TEXT(A13,""))+COUNTIFS('Los Angeles Night Shift'!O:O,"Ongoing",'Los Angeles Night Shift'!L:L,TEXT(A13,""))),"")
```

My code is:

```
Worksheets("NIC Status Day Shift").Select
Range("B13").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IF(COUNTIF(RC[-1],""<>""),(COUNTIFS('Night Shift'!C[13],""Ongoing"",'Night Shift'!C[9],TEXT(RC[-1],""""))+COUNTIFS('Night Shift'!C[13],""Ongoing"",'Night Shift'!C[10],TEXT(RC[-1],""""))+COUNTIFS('Los Angeles Night Shift'!C[13],""Ongoing"",'Los Angeles Night Shift'!C[9],TEXT(RC[-1],""""))+COUNTIFS('Los Angeles Night Shift'!C[13],""Ongoing"",'Los Angeles Night Shift'" & _
    "EXT(RC[-1],""""))),"""")"
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("B13:B35"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("B13:B35").Select
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
```

Can any one please help me to fix this.

Comment: Please add details to your question about the "one problem" you are having.

Comment: One obvious problem is that the first line of formula ends with `'Los Angeles Night Shift'`, second starts with `EXT`. Some part is missing at the break of line (probably `!C[9],T`

Comment: @user3964075 much appreciate your comment, already fix the issue, thanks